# I want to know SQL commands

Tags: sql

i want to display the employee names which having names start with a and end with h ,it should be like list will display employees with 'a' as a first letter and the 'h' as a last etter...

so any body tell me what is the command to display these...

Comment: google it or at least add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select * 
from employee 
where
 name like's%' 
and 
name like'%h';

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name LIKE 'a%h'`

You say it has to start with s and then you say it has to start with a, which is it?

Also, this is just a generic query, we can't know the exact SQL query because you didn't show your table structure.

Comment: SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name LIKE 's%h''

Comment: Sorry for that it is 'a' not 's'...

Comment: @Mike oops, forgot about that.

Comment: @SandeepChauhan you basically said it is an a but it is not an a

Comment: @SandeepChauhan I see you edited your comment, then the query will work as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by the following code:
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name LIKE 'a%h'

Note:In here "name" means, the column which is containing employee names.